# How to stop a MockRunner with SoapUI?

Tags: java, web-services, jetty, soapui

I have code that looks something like:

```
public void stopService(WsdlMockService service) {
    log("Stopping mock service");

    int attempts = 10;

    service.getMockRunner().stop();
    while(service.getMockRunner().isRunning() && attempts-- > 0) {
        sleep(5000);
        log("Service now " + (service.getMockRunner().isRunning() ? "running" : "stopped"));
    }

    if(service.getMockRunner().isRunning()) {
        log("Failed to stop service");
    }
}
```

This, seemingly without fail, produces the following output:

```
 - Stopping mock service
 - Service now running
 - Service now running
 - Service now running
 - Service now running
 - Service now running
 - Service now running
 - Service now running
 - Service now running
 - Service now running
 - Service now running
 - Service now running
 - Failed to stop service
```

Is there a better / correct way to stop a WebService once started?

Comment: Which version of soapUI ?

Comment: Your code looks  good as per #7 of http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/tips---tricks.html